# Is the set {p | Lp is context free} decidable, semidecidable, or not semidecidable?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, decidability

I have done some research and I know that it can be proven that every CFL is decidable (for example: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f719/739f07c24c3790b63f3274037522b0b831c8.pdf). This means that we can build a TM/algorithm which takes a CFL and a word w and tells whether this word w belongs to CFL, and this algorithm halts.

But I don't know if this fact can be used to prove that the set {p | Lp is context free} is decidable. As far as I'm concerned, the problem of saying whether a set is decidable or not is that we can build an algorithm that halts that can tell in finite time whether an element belongs to this set or not.

Edit: Let me clarify. p is a program. Lp is L(p), the language of the words accepted by p.

Comment: What is the definition of Lp ?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The problem just states "Lp", but I think it is equivalent to L(p), so, the language of the words/strings/whatever accepted by P.

Comment: And what is P? A Turing machine, or a context-sensitive grammar, or what?

Comment: @Andreas Blass I believe p is supposed to be a program.

Comment: In that case, Rice's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem) shows that your set isn't decidable, and a well-known extension of that theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%E2%80%93Shapiro_theorem) shows that it isn't even semi-decidable.

Comment: @Andreas Blass Excellent! Thanks. Apart from using these theorems, could I try a reduction from the complement of K? Something like: if (input = a) accept; run Mx; if (input = {set of words of a non-CFL) accept;

Comment: I would expect a reduction from the complement of the halting problem can be used here, but it would need to be more complicated than what you proposed, since "input = {set of words of a non-CFL}" isn't a decidable condition (even after you fix a specific non-CFL).

Comment: OK, understood. Thanks. I still don't close the question because someone could provide more information, but your comments have been very useful.